# Which is the simplest way to redirect to page when user is not logged in in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two simple login and home controllers:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
        public LoginController()
        {
            
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public HomeController()
        {
            
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I would like to redirect to login/index every time when user is not logged in. How can I achieve that? Thank you very much.

Comment: have a look at the AuthorizeAttribute to start with...

Comment: You can achieve with [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs). Checkout this [demo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-filter-in-mvc-with-an-example/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Authorize` attribute which as part of `Forms` authentication in ASP.NET-MVC. To do that you need to setup forms authentication first in your web.config:

Under the `<system.web>` element, place:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Now in your `LoginController`, when you are authenticating a user, it will be something like this:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
        public LoginController()
        {
            
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {               
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult ValidateUser()
        {
          //your user authentication logic here
          if(userAuthenticated)
          {
             FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userModel, false);
          }
  
           return View("Index");
        }
}
```

Once you have authenticated your user, then you can place the `Authorize` attribute either on class action or method depending on your need:

Require authorized user only to access entire class and its methods:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Require user to only be authorized for `Index` method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```